# Force session ID from request

Tags: php, session, request

Does anyone have any thoughts about why this wouldn't work?

```
    if(isset($_POST['PHPSESSID'])) {
session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
}
```

The var_dump($_SESSION); is always empty! It should be loaded with stuff! Are there any settings that prevent forcing session IDs? Auto start is not enabled.

Comment: your vulnerable to session hijacking btw.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Please elaborate

Comment: well if i got my hands ona session_id from another member, I could inject that via POST and use the session of another member, accessing data that i should not be able to access !

Comment: @Robert **if** you got your hands on a SID, why not to inject it via cookie as well?

Comment: theres nothing to stop me, apart from on my end i would have md5 checks in place to validate a hash, session_regenerate_id will be used etc.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is correct.  However, you may not be seeing variables in your session for one of several reasons:

- `$_POST['PHPSESSID']` is not set
- `$_POST['PHPSESSID']` contains non-numeric characters
- `$_POST['PHPSESSID']` does not refer to a populated session ID
- `session_start()` was called before your call to `session_id`

If none of these apply, I don't know what the issue is, but why don't you try using `session_name()` (which was designed for what you're trying to do) instead of `session_id`?

Comment: Thank you. The variable is set, because the var_dump in the if(isset()) block is happening, so I know that is returning true. By "non-numeric" did you mean "non-alphanumeric?" Can you explain how to do this with session_name()?

Comment: My understanding, confirmed by the link, is that session_name() is the name of the session cookie, but session_id() is the unique value. I've confirmed that the value of session_name() is "PHPSESSID" (the default value), so whether it's hardcoded or retrieve with that function, I'm not seeing how it would make a difference?

Comment: @Aaron Carlino: What I judged your code to be attempting to do is to segregate this particular session from all the other random sessions.  Assigning it a different `session_name` does that, no?  If you really want to "pick up" an old session, you'd also have to locate the ID, yes.  About illegal characters, "Depending on the session handler, not all characters are allowed within the session id. For example, the file session handler only allows characters in the range a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and - (minus)".

Comment: I'm actually not doing anything that complicated. I'm just trying to authenticate a Flash upload script. As you may know, when the Flash component executes a PHP script, it starts a new session, so I'm trying to force the session by posting the session ID through the request. It works in most environments. I can't understand why it would fail in some.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_POST['PHPSESSID']` must be wrong :

> Depending on the session handler, not all characters are allowed within the session id. For example, the *file session handler* only allows characters in the range *a-z A-Z 0-9 , (comma) and - (minus)*

Check its value. If you changed the session handler, you must use only the allowed characters for this specific session handler.

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - sessionid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Comment: $_POST['PHPSESSID'] is coming in as "88rbfemtnma9padi34kfm7imk0". session.save_handler is "files" This makes me crazy. I can confirm the session id exists because in another browser I'm doing var_dump(session_id()) and it's returning the exact value that's coming in through the request.

Answer (score -1):

There was an issue with the session save path. It wasn't set up right, so I can guess that PHP was relying on browser cookies to create the session instead of the files in the session save path.